# Pole of differential

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E : y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$ be an elliptic curve over the field $K$, char $K \ne 0$.

We know that the differential $\omega = \frac{dx}{y}$ is holomorphic in infinity because we can write it as $\frac{2 dy}{3x^2 + a}$.

I can't understand, though, how $x \omega$ has a double pole at infinity. I can't make sense of it.

Comment: $x / y$ is a rational function with a simple pole at infinity. Do you understand that calculation?

Comment: @ZhenLin Not entirely - when I think of infinity as $[0:1:0]$, $x$ as $X/Z$ and $y$ as $Y/Z$ then it looks like it would have a zero instead...

Comment: That's not correct. Both $x$ and $y$ evaluate to $\infty$ at $[0 : 1 : 0]$. (Otherwise $x$ and $y$ would be functions that are regular everywhere on a projective variety, hence, constant – an absurdity.)

Comment: @ZhenLin You must be right. Now that I think about it, if $K$ were $\mathbb{C}$ we would take $x = \wp$ and it has a double pole. I'm not sure how to prove this in general